# Is that possible to do the same (hover effect) without Javascript (only CSS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a button with icon [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/pRdMc/):

HTML:

```
<div id='button'>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <span>Send Email</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
    width: 270px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #555;
    position: relative;
}
#button > .icon {
    width: 61px;
    height: 39px;
    background-image: url('http://i55.tinypic.com/2agsutj.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 5px;
}
#button > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
    top: 10px;
}
#button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').hover(function() {
        $('#button > .icon').css('background-position', '0px -39px');
    }, function() {
        $('#button > .icon').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    });
});
```

My question is: Is Javascript really necessary for such simple functionality, or it can be done using CSS only ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a `:hover` pseudoclass for that.

```
#button:hover > .icon {
    background-position: 0px -39px;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_hover.asp

Comment: Note that you'd like to add a http://ie6nomore.com banner to your site then. It namely doesn't support it.

Comment: Of course, IE6 is an orphan, even at MS. The team working on IE9 sent flowers to the pseudo-funeral held for IE6. http://blog.seattlepi.com/microsoft/archives/196608.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Ya 100%**

> [Working demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/pRdMc/9/)

in the above example you need to use hover and shift

> background position

uisng css. you can do it without javascript for sure.

here is ***working solution*** dont require any javascript

**html**

```
<div id='button'>
    <span class='icon'>Send Email</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
​#button span{
    display:block;
    padding-left:80px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #555;
    line-height:1.4em;
}
#button span.icon{
    background-image: url('http://i55.tinypic.com/2agsutj.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width:120px;
    height:39px;
}
#button:hover span{
color:#fff;
}n
#button:hover span.icon{
    background-image: url('http://i55.tinypic.com/2agsutj.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -39px;

}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p47jR/11/) with "a" tag so hover works in IE too.

```
<div id="button">
<a href="#text" name="text">Send Email</a>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#button {
    width: 270px;
    height: 45px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background-color: #555;
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 15px;    
}

#button a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    padding:5px;
    padding-left: 65px;
    background-image: url('http://i55.tinypic.com/2agsutj.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;    
}

#button a:hover {
   background-position:0px -39px;
   color: #fff;
}
```